# The difference between Handler.dispatchMessage(msg) and Handler.sendMessage(msg)

Tags: android, handler

When I use `Handler.dispatchMessage(msg)`, the `handleMessage(Message msg)` will be run on new thread but when I use `Handler.sendMessage(msg)`, the `handleMessage(Message msg)` will be run on main thread. Who can tell me the difference between them?

Thanks!

Demo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private String TAG = "MainActivity";
private Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Handler:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " & arg1=" + msg.arg1);
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(TAG, "Main:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    testMethod();
}

private void testMethod()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1 = 1;
            mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
            Message msg2 = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg2.arg1 = 2;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
        }

    };
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Output:

```
04-19 11:32:10.452: INFO/MainActivity(774): Main:1
04-19 11:32:10.488: INFO/MainActivity(774): Thread:8
04-19 11:32:10.492: INFO/MainActivity(774): Handler:8 & arg1=1
04-19 11:32:10.635: INFO/MainActivity(774): Handler:1 & arg1=2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg)` is like directly calling `handleMessage(Message msg)` and I don't know when that would be useful. The point of Handlers is the ability to send messages to other threads. That's what you do with `sendMessage`.

Edit: as you can see it just calls `handleMessage()` for you.

```
/**
 * Handle system messages here.
 */
public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.callback != null) {
        // callback = the Runnable you can post "instead of" Messages.
        msg.callback.run();
    } else {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            if (mCallback.handleMessage(msg)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Waqas from your code `mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg)` - it's the sourcecode for `Handler.dispatchMessage` (slightly simplified)

Comment: yes but *dispatchMessage(Message msg)* says **msg**, but in code its also using **message** which is whom i'm concerning about

Comment: oops, my fault, I've inlined [some code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.handleCallback%28android.os.Message%29) there and failed to correct the name.

Answer (score 3):

If You Call the `Handler.dispatchMessage()` in the Main Thread Then The Message is processed in Main Thread.

If You Call The `Handler.dispatchMessage()` in the Worker Thread Then The Message is Processed in Worker Thread.

When You Call `Handler.sendMessage(msg)` The Message is Processed in the Thread Which Created The Handler.

Answer (score 1):

The messages sent with `Handler.sendMessage()` will be handled on the thread you created in `testMethod()`.

The messages sent with `Handler.dispatchMessage()` are handled on the **`main`** thread.

Comment: I think you mis-read the question and wrote it in the wrong way. `sendMessage`'s messages handled in main thread and `dispatchMessage`'s messages handled in the newly created message. You are also not answering to the question of `Why?`