# Handler.dispatchMessage hangs/crashes when used from OpenGL thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I'm working on an opengl game for Android. When user looses the game should return to main menu, but this call is to be done from OpenGl ES thread to UI thread and there is some troubles. I've found this post [Pass variables between renderer and another class with queueEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417859/pass-variables-between-renderer-and-another-class-with-queueevent/8420243#8420243) and tried to add Handler class in the following code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView gameView;
    private int menuViewID;

    private Handler gameOverHandler;

    public GameActivity () {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameOverHandler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage (Message msg){
                handleGameOver();
            }
        };
        gameView = new GameView(this, gameOverHandler);
        menuViewID = R.layout.main;

        setContentView(menuViewID);
    }

    /** Called when the user selects the Send button */
    public void startGame(View view) {
        setContentView(gameView);
        gameView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void handleGameOver() {
        /**
         * TODO: switch back to main menu
         */

//      setContentView(menuViewID);         // after this gameView freezes
//      gameView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // after this application throw an error: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.


    }
}
```

and then later in OpenGL ES code

```
gameOverHandler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(gameOverHandler));
```

but I'm still getting a freeze or runtime exception (see commented lines in the code above). What I'm missing here or doing wrong?

By the way, how to get the reference for the View instance that was defined in XML (see `menuViewID` in the code above), or why the `findViewById` method returns `NULL`?

Comment: Have you looked at `runOnUiThread`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: No I hasn't before, but it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the `dispatchMessage(msg)` method.  That is apparently the same as calling the Handler directly. (The documentation is poor.  It seems it's intended for system use).

See similar question here:

[The difference between Handler.dispatchMessage(msg) and Handler.sendMessage(msg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227219/the-difference-between-handler-dispatchmessagemsg-and-handler-sendmessagemsg)

Instead, you could use this:

```
gameOverHandler.obtainMessage(MY_MSG_INT_ID).sendToTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to handle it in the UI thread? I can handle it just fine from my Game Class  using this code:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, EndGameActivity.class);
    ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

I just cast the context from the UI thread activity back into an activity, and then start my new activity for a result from there. I send back a result and then in my activity on the UI thread i catch  the result like so:

```
    @Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    if (resultCode == 1) { 
       this.finish(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Am I right, that you offer several activities: one for main menu, one for game itself and one for results menu? Will your scheme work with only one activity? I have really small game, several activities is too much, to my mind.

Comment: Yes, I do have several activities, hmmmm I didn't realize we were trying to work with a single one here... It wont work this way with a single activity. In this case it would seem that either the way you were describing, or possibly passing down a pointer to your activity into your non-UI thread will have to do. I haven't tried with 1 activity before.

Comment: I'll check your solution later, maybe on bigger projects )
Anyway, thanks for help!