# How to create handler with callbacks that run on a different thread?

Tags: android, android-handler

I am trying to create a `Handler` that will handle messages on its own thread

What I am currently doing is running during the `onCreate` part of the activity this code:

```
lateinit var _handler: Handler
lateinit var hThread: HandlerThread

fun setUpHandler() {
    hThread = HandlerThread("HandlerThread")
    hThread.start()
    _handler = Handler(hThread.looper, this::callback)
}
```

the problem is that even though I use a different thread's looper the callback runs on the ui thread.

I tested it by running creating this method:

```
fun callback(msg: Message): Boolean {
    Log.d("Handler", "got message ${msg.what} in thread main? ${Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()}")
    return true
}
```

when I call it like this:

```
_handler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(_handler, 1))
```

I get:

```
Handler: got message 1 in thread main? true
```

but when I run it like this:

```
Handler(hThread.looper).post {
    val msg = Message.obtain()
    msg.what = 2
    callback(msg)
}
```

I get this message:

```
Handler: got message 2 in thread main? false
```

I currently use the second approach, but out of curiosity , is there a way to make the first approach work?

as a side question, is running `hThread.quit()` in the activity's `onDestroy` method enough to terminate the extra Thread I started or do I have to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227219/the-difference-between-handler-dispatchmessagemsg-and-handler-sendmessagemsg) the `dispatchMessage` function runs the `Message` through the `callback` on whatever Thread the function is called on... so since your calling it from the UI Thread that's where it appears.

Also FYI `dispatchMessage` isn't really used as it defeats the purpose of using a `Handler` and attaching it to a `Thread` etc as perfectly demonstrated here.

`quit()` terminates the `Looper` which essentially terminates the infinite `while` loop in effect that keeps the `HandlerThread` "alive" in it's `run()` method, so yes, it should be enough to kill the `Thread` itself. However, beware that any `Message` or `Runnable` currently already executing will not be stopped, and all other `Messages` or `Runnables` in the `MessageQueue` of the `Looper` will not be executed.